# Simulator does not show button text

Tags: button, ios6, ios-simulator, xcode4.5

I'm learning to build iPhone apps with XCode 4.5.2 and I noticed something strange. As you can see at the address https://i.stack.imgur.com/purI8.jpg the text inside one of the buttons is not displayed in the iOS6 simulator. I also tried to move the Enter button in the same line of 0 and -, but the text in all three buttons of the line disappeared. Anyone knows what's the cause of this problem and how to solve it? Here is the code:

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;
@end

@implementation CalculatorViewController

@synthesize display;
@synthesize userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
@synthesize brain = _brain;

- (CalculatorBrain *)brain
{
    if (!_brain) _brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    return _brain;
}

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{    
    NSString *digit = [sender currentTitle];
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) {
        self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
    } else {
        self.display.text = digit;
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)enterPressed
{
     [self.brain pushOperand:[self.display.text doubleValue]];
     self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;
}

- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) [self enterPressed];

    NSString *operation = [sender currentTitle];
    double result = [self.brain performOperation:operation];
    self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];
}

@end
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't put it because the button text is not set through code, but if you need it here's the code of the view. The action related to the button is enterPressed.

Comment: Yes, I only needed to disable autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW7

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state
```

To set your button titles.

So in your case:

```
- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
   ....
   [sender setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

   // lets assume you want the down states as well:
   [sender setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
   [sender setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

}